# Retrieve Access Token for Quire API - unsupported_grant_type

Tags: quire-api

I am attempting to Retrieve Access Token following the directions in the api docs (https://quire.io/dev/api/)

Example curl request

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"grant_type":"authorization_code","code":"my_code","client_id":"my_client_id","client_secret":"my_client_secret"}' https://quire.io/oauth/token
```

I only receive this response:

```
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"The supported grant types are 'authorization_code', 'refresh_token'."}
```

Can you see anything wrong with my curl request?

by [Anderson Reinkordt](https://quire.io/w/Quire_Feedbacks/2926)

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a duplicate of: [Exchange Quire authorization code for access token with GM_xmlhttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362125/exchange-quire-authorization-code-for-access-token-with-gm-xmlhttprequest)

Explained/accepted in this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58370352/4740707

Since the error message is a bit misleading please vote for:
https://github.com/quire-api/quire-api/issues/9